# How to return a single data from a row from a table in html?

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a table that stores the product in the cart of a user. Each row has a button that enables the user to remove a single product from the cart of a user. Here is the code snippet of my html.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/removeProduct" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="${page}">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${productsInCart}" var="product"
                    varStatus="status">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="upc"
                            value="${product.getUpc()}">
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <td>${product.getName()}</td>
                        <td>${product.getQuantity()}</td>
                        <td style="color: green;">&#8369; ${product.getTotal()}</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
                            value="Remove from cart"></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Here is the output.

[Product in cart table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S8j0.png)

The value I want to get is the UPC of a product which is stored in a hidden input type field. However, when the 'remove from cart' button is clicked, it returns all the UPC of the product that is in the cart. Here is the code snippet of the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/removeProduct", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeProduct(@RequestParam(value = "upc") String upc, HttpServletRequest request){

    System.out.println(upc);
//      customerService.removeProductInCart(customer.getCustomer(request).getCartId(), upc);

    return "customer_home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create form on every iteration to get the specific upc on each row instead of wrapping your whole table.